# Exclude all rows of a file of key strings contained in some other file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a Windows batch file where there are two files in concern.

The first file `all.err` contains logs of failed test cases like below:

```
`CHECK:FAIL,"It should have been DEST`"
`CHECK:FAIL,"It should have been XYZA`"
`CHECK:FAIL,"It should have been PRTS`"
`CHECK:FAIL,"It should have been ABCD`"
.....................................
```

We have another file `exclude.txt` which stores some string per line like:

```
XYZA
ABCD
```

I am trying to write a Windows batch script which can list all lines from `all.err` that do not contain any word in `exclude.txt`.

I am not able to understand how this can be implemented - any idea?

Comment: Do you absolutely need it in cmd? I'd rather make it in Python. Or at least in PowerShell.

Comment: Check out the output of `findstr /?`, specifically the `/G` and `/V` flags.

Comment: Can you please clarify that your `all.err` file content lines really look like this `\`CHECK:FAIL,"It should have been DEST\`"`. I ask because the position of the back ticks looks completely wrong.

Comment: Are you also sure that you're wanting to list the lines from `all.err`? I ask because I don't see a real world scenario where that would be as useful as outputting, `1:\`CHECK:FAIL,"It should have been DEST\`"` and `3:\`CHECK:FAIL,"It should have been PRTS\`"`, or `DEST` and `PRTS` or even `1:DEST` and `3:PRTS`.

Comment: @aparpara why? this is a very simple job for a `batch-file` to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `for` loop, you need to go through exclusions file first, get each line, then exclude these meta viariables from your search in the log file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (exclude.txt) do (
     for /f "delims=" %%b in ('type all.log ^| findstr /V "%%i"') do echo(%%b
)
```

The first `do` code block is not needed, I simply posted it like that for readability, it simply can be:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (exclude.txt) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ('type all.log ^| findstr /V "%%i"') do echo(%%b
```

Answer (score 6):

There is just one Windows command line necessary for this task as written by [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark):

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /G:exclude.txt all.err
```

The help output on running in a Windows command prompt window `findstr /?` explains the parameters `/I` (case-**i**nsensitive), `/L` (search strings are **l**iteral strings), `/V` (in**v**erse matching output), `/G` (**g**et search strings from file).

Comment: If the content of the first non empty line in `exclude.txt` is a valid regular expression, then all search strings will be treated as `/R`egular expressions. As we don't know the actual content, I would advise the use of the `/L` option to prevent that from happening.